# Modeling Weather Predictions

Tags: python, dataframe, regression

So I have a dataframe of severe weather from 1950-present. I want to use it to predict the requency of future storms. The way the database is set up, each row is a unique observation. The columns are as follows:

```
Index(['BEGIN_TIME', 'END_TIME', 'EVENT_ID', 'STATE', 'STATE_FIPS',
       'EVENT_TYPE', 'CZ_FIPS', 'BEGIN_DATE_TIME', 'END_DATE_TIME',
       'INJURIES_DIRECT', 'INJURIES_INDIRECT', 'DEATHS_DIRECT',
       'DEATHS_INDIRECT', 'DAMAGE_PROPERTY', 'SOURCE', 'MAGNITUDE',
       'MAGNITUDE_TYPE', 'FLOOD_CAUSE', 'CATEGORY', 'BEGIN_LOCATION',
       'END_LOCATION', 'DATA_SOURCE', 'BEGIN_DATE'],
      dtype='object')
```

So far, I am able to plot the number of storms per year as follows:

```
event_counts = thunderstorm_df['BEGIN_DATE'].dt.year.value_counts().sort_index()

# Create a bar graph
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
event_counts.plot(kind='bar', color='blue')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Number of Thunderstorm Wind Events')
plt.title('Total Thunderstorm Wind Events Per Year')
plt.grid(axis='y')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I'm clearly missing something here but what do I need to do to fit this for linear regression?

Comment: You're using Pandas, right? It'd help to mention that, to be clear. You can [edit]. BTW, for more tips, check out [ask].